# Grouping if statements

Tags: html, css, if-statement, conditional-statements, liquid

I'm trying to find a way to have the "if contains" conditions all appear in one line rather than having to repeat the code every single time.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
var selector = document.querySelector('tr[data-variant-id="{{ item.variant.id }}"] .product__description__variant');
    {% assign pre_order_message = '' %}
    {% for tag in item.product.tags %}
        {% if tag contains 'weeks' %}
            {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}                                    
            {% assign pre_order_message = tag | split:'**' | last %}                          
             var para = document.createElement("p");
             para.classList.add('hc-shipping');

            var node = document.createTextNode("Expected to begin shipping {{ pre_order_message }} from order date.");
             para.appendChild(node);
             selector.after(para);
        {% endif %}  
    {% endfor %}  
 
   var selector = document.querySelector('tr[data-variant-id="{{ item.variant.id }}"] .product__description__variant');
    {% assign pre_order_message = '' %}
    {% for tag in item.product.tags %}
        {% if tag contains 'January' %}
            {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}                                    
            {% assign pre_order_message = tag | split:'**' | last %}                          
             var para = document.createElement("p");
             para.classList.add('hc-shipping');

            var node = document.createTextNode("Expected to begin shipping {{ pre_order_message }}.");
             para.appendChild(node);
             selector.after(para);
        {% endif %}  
    {% endfor %}
```

I just want to make sure I can group together what lies between the ' ... ' on the line, that states {% if tag contains '   ' %}. Any way to fix? Thanks!

Comment: what template engine is this ?

Comment: this is just in Shopify's checkout.liquid

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and/or` to combine conditions, more info about this [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/control-flow-tags#multiple-conditions-and-or).

By the way if you just want to make sure a tag exists in product tags, you can do this:

```
{% if item.product.tags contains 'weeks' %}
  Do something...
{% endif %}
```

Instead of looping through all the tags, you'll save a couple of lines that way ;)

One last thing, you can DRY the code by using code snippets, here's a [quick read](https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/88186566-tips-for-using-snippets-in-your-shopify-theme) about this.